# Do Markov chains preserve measurability of functions?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let $(S,\mathcal{S})$ be a measurable space, and let $p: S \times \mathcal{S} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies the properties: $p(s,\cdot)$ is a measure for each $s \in S$ and $p(\cdot, A)$ is a measurable function on $S$ for each $A \in \mathcal{S}$.

Let $f$ be a measurable function on $S$, assumed to be non-negative or bounded. Let $A \in \mathcal{S}$. In this case, is the function $x \mapsto \int_A f(y) p(x,dy)$ measurable?

Comment: Simple function approximation.

Comment: Yes this is true. This is probably proven in Kallenberg's book *"Random measures"*.